# Run task once a week on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My site is hosted on Heroku, I need to run a task once a week. The scheduler addon only allows me to run tasks once a day ... anyway I can change that?

My site is written in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if today is a monday and don't run your task otherwise.

```
Time.now.wday
=> 2
```

0: Sunday .. 6: Saturday

Answer (score 5):

Or do the same check from the scheduler task

```
test `date +%w` -eq 2 && rake ...
```

Again 0: Sunday ... 6: Saturday

Comment: For those users reading this, this solution is way better when you're loading application environment on some tasks since the task initialization takes a while but the script execution is instant.